# What does this bash operator do? (slash dot)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

What does `\. <name of a script>` do in bash?

I found it in this context:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

I tried searching for it by I always have a hard time searching symbols.

Comment: Please show output of `alias .`.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html

Comment: Thanks for that link

Comment: Cyrus, `alias .` gives an error status code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.` sources another file. You can search "dot command in shell" and read for example the posix docs https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/dot.html .

The `\<some_command>` runs the command without an alias. You could potentially have like:

```
alias .=cat
```

and then `. file` would cat the file, but `\. file` will still source the file.

Answer (score 1):

It quotes the character before it so it can't be acted upon in another way.  In the above case, I'm surprised its there since typically the single '.' would be functionally "run that file in my local environment" -- another name would be "source" it, which is the name of the CSH similar command.  The '' is likely protecting it from security issues like @kamilcuk said.

```
echo echo hi > foo.sh

[ -s foo.sh ] && . foo.sh
hi

[ -s foo.sh ] && \. foo.sh
hi
```